# The potential function of Prisoner's Dilemma

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, algorithmic-game-theory

As in the famous example of "Prisoner's Dilemma" like this

[image]

If the potential function is defined as: (V(q,q), V(q,c), V(c,q), V(c,c))
q = quiet, c = confess, V is the potential.

So should the order be: **V(q,q) > V(q,c) = V(c,q) > V(c,c)**??

EX: (3,1,1,0)

Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by potential. The numbers here refer to the length of the sentence, e.g. years in prison. So, each player wants to minimize what they get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential for the unique pure Nash equilibrium should be the *lowest* potential value, not the highest. This is because the utilities correspond to **costs** (as noted by  jmbejara in the comments to the question).

For this game the following matrix corresponds to a potential $P$, which should be **minimized** since the utilities in the original game are **costs**: $$P=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 4\\
4 & 6\\
\end{array} \right).$$
In fact $P$ is an **exact** potential, since the change in the potential for a deviation is **equal** to change in the deviating player's utility. For example when player one switches from (Stay quiet, Stay quiet) to (Confess, Stay quiet), his utility increases by 2.